# 9Patch Images for Android Toggle Button

Tags: android

I have a requirement for a Toggle button in Android. I have been trying to find 9patch images for my toggle button but so far no success. Can someone please help me. I did not think it would be so difficult, but cannot find any help anywhere ?

Kind Regards

Comment: The odds of finding ready to use `9-patch` images specific to your requirements are kinda stacked up against you. Try this link: http://www.mokasocial.com/2011/07/sexily-styled-toggle-buttons-for-android/. It has a tutorial to create a nice looking `9-patch`. Perhaps it could help.

Comment: I tried it, but to no avail. Tried creating my own but got nothing

Comment: Well, `9-patch` images are known to be a pain in the rear anyway. ;-) Unfortunately, no shortcuts available there. The other best suggestion I can make is playing with your images. This link might be able to make things easier for ya: http://android-ui-utils.googlecode.com/hg/asset-studio/dist/nine-patches.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are very unspecific about what you want the button to look like... You can find the android native toggle buttons in following folder (mdpi folder and for api lvl 14) and see how they are made: `C:\Android\android-sdk\platforms\android-14\data\res\drawable-mdpi`

Search for: toggle.

There is also the switch which was implemented in android from api lvl 14:

The switch graphic can be found in same folder just search for: switch.

Comment: I wanted a kind of the switch button. I found the buttons, can u show me how i can get the look of the toggle button like used in the ICS Preferences screen like for the WIFI.

Comment: @user365019 first of all you can only get that look and feel with the switch which only works from api 14 (ice cream). But if you want to duplicate the buttons graphic, you should look into the drawables/ folder and find the selector for the switch button. Its not that easy though as they sometimes use many different selectors.

Answer (score 1):

Hey why search for 9 patch images when you can create one for yourself. It's really simple to create. Here is a [link](http://radleymarx.com/blog/simple-guide-to-9-patch/) for creating 9-patch. It's a very good tutorial for learning 9-patch.